# MySql Select Statement Issue

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am not sure what I am trying to achieve here is called which is why I will try to explain with pictures.

[image]

Below is the query that I have got:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
unspsc_commodity.`name` AS Commodity,
unspsc_code.`code` AS `Code`,
attributes.`value`
FROM
products
INNER JOIN unspsc_code ON products.unspsc_code_id =     unspsc_code.unspsc_code_id
INNER JOIN unspsc_commodity ON unspsc_code.unspsc_commodity_id =   unspsc_commodity.unspsc_commodity_id
INNER JOIN attributes ON products.product_id = attributes.product_id
WHERE attributes.`name` = 'Product Type'
```

Above query only select unspsc_commodity, unspsc_code and value where attribute.name has 'Product Type'. I would like to select unspsc_commodity, unspsc_code for products where there is no Product Type too. So where there is no Product Type in attribute table the query needs to select just the code and commodity and just output null for value. Is it possible to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to have `LEFT JOIN` like below and move the `WHERE` condition in select clause with a `CASE` expression

```
SELECT DISTINCT
unspsc_commodity.`name` AS Commodity,
unspsc_code.`code` AS `Code`,
CASE WHEN IFNULL(attributes.`name`,'') = 'Product Type' THEN attributes.`value` ELSE NULL END AS Value
FROM
products
INNER JOIN unspsc_code 
ON products.unspsc_code_id = unspsc_code.unspsc_code_id
INNER JOIN unspsc_commodity 
ON unspsc_code.unspsc_commodity_id = unspsc_commodity.unspsc_commodity_id
LEFT JOIN attributes 
ON products.product_id = attributes.product_id;
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul that does what I needed. Will you please be able to tell me how can I had another case as I would like to select data where the attribute.name has product type and form factor

Comment: @user4676307, it can be like general syntax `case when condirtion then value when con2 then val2 else val3 end`

Comment: I get the case statement but will I have another left joint for attribute table ? LEFT JOIN attributes AS attributes_2 ON products.product_id = attributes_2.product_id

Comment: CASE WHEN attributes_2.`name` = 'Form Factor' THEN attributes_2.`value` ELSE NULL END AS Value

Comment: @user4676307, No No, just use a IN operator in my answer like `CASE WHEN IFNULL(attributes.`name`,'')  IN ('Product Type' ,'From actor')`

Comment: Will this output both product type and form factor ?

Comment: I added another attribute joint before is because products have both product type and form factor values in attributes tables and I need to select both separately as different column

Comment: @user4676307, if you want them to be separate column then yes do a separate left join and use a case statement like what you said in earlier comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89920/discussion-between-user4676307-and-rahul).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
unspsc_commodity.`name` AS Commodity,
unspsc_code.`code` AS `Code`,
attributes.`value`
FROM
products
INNER JOIN unspsc_code ON products.unspsc_code_id =     unspsc_code.unspsc_code_id
INNER JOIN unspsc_commodity ON unspsc_code.unspsc_commodity_id =   unspsc_commodity.unspsc_commodity_id
INNER JOIN attributes ON products.product_id = attributes.product_id
WHERE 1
```

Comment: I can not remove "attributes.`name` = 'Product Type'" from where statement as attributes tables is has loads of other name and I only need to select where attribute.name is product type